# Looking for a few sample XML report files for Cognos 10 or 11

Tags: xml, cognos-bi

I am looking for a few cognos report xml files for some testing I am doing.  It doesn't matter what model or what package, etc... I am just looking for real examples.  I was looking to download the sample zip file, but it's useless without installing a cognos instance.

Is anyone willing to share either a handful of the gosales reports and dashboard xml files? or any other?